# What is different in these two approaches regarding Linked Lists? 1 argument vs 2 arguements in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

This bit of code inserts at the tail of a linked list and it works perfectly when the head node is not null, i.e. it already points to some linked list.

```
    void Insert(node *head,int x)
{



    if (head==NULL)
    {   
        head=new node;
        head->key=x;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        link=head;
        while (link->next!=NULL)
        {
            link=link->next;
        }

        link->next=new node;
        link->next->key=x;
        link->next->next=NULL;
    }

}
```

For the first part of the code, if the head node is Null, which it initially is, I simply put in the data and pointer in the node.

When its not null, the 'link' node begins at the head of the list and traverses till the tail, therein I put in the node.

This bit of code below, which only takes one function works in all cases. Why is that? head is equal to NULL and globally defined in both cases.

```
void insert(int x)
{
    if (head==NULL)
    {   
        head=new node;
        head->key=x;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        link=head;
        while (link->next!=NULL)
        {
            link=link->next;
        }

        link->next=new node;
        link->next->key=x;
        link->next->next=NULL;
    }
}
```

Note: This is not an assignment or homework or anything related. I am just trying to learn basic stuff regarding linked lists and this is a problem i came across while doing some stuff on Hacker Rank.

In case anyone's interested in the display function:

```
void display()
{
    node *trav=head;
    while (trav!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<trav->key;
        trav=trav->next;
    }
}
```

Struct has been defined in my program.

```
struct node
{    
    int key;
    node *next;
}
```

For the sake of convenience, I have defined head pointer globally, but with some slight adjustments i could change that. I think. Also 'link' is also global in case anyone's confused where it came from.

```
node *head = NULL;
node *link = NULL;
```

So to summarize, the question is :

Why does it work in one argument but not for the two arguments version when head is NULL.

Comment: The difference is the second one doesn't compile because you forgot to return anything.

Comment: Thank you for your input guys. I am incredibly sorry I posted two of the same codes. I have updated that now. The question is why does it work in one arguement but not for the two arguements version when head is NULL.

Comment: What does `void f(int x) {x = 5;}` then `int y = 7; f(y); cout << y << endl;` print, and why?

Comment: It outputs 7. Well I guess the function only modifies the local variable. I understood, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first function, where you pass `head` as an argument, you pass the argument *by value*. That means inside the function `head` is a *copy* of the value you pass when calling the function, and modifying a copy will not modify the original.

You need to pass the argument *by reference*, which is easily done in C++ using the ampersand (`&`) when declaring the argument:

```
void Insert(node *& head,int x) { ... }
//                ^
// Note ampersand here
```

That tells the compiler that `head` is a *reference* to the original variable you use when you call the function.

Comment: Despite knowing this concept I made this mistake. This clears it up perfectly. Thank you sir.

Comment: I'm not sure that modification is needed though, the variable is being passed via pointer. The pointer is being copied, not the element that it is pointing too. Having a reference to a pointer shouldn't change the behavior of the code.

Comment: @AlexZywicki It depends on how the function is called, but most likely a pointer variable is used when calling the function, which means the contents of the variable (i.e. the actual pointer) is *copied* into the local variable `head` in the function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I took a closer look at the OP's code and i see how it would make a difference